# how to use xerces in java?

Tags: java, xml, xerces

This is my code for validation of xml only problem i am having is in line 2 while importing org.apache.xerces...i downloaded xerces.jar and then added it as external jar into class from run configuration,can you just tell me if i am doing it write if yes then why this error if no then what should i do.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser;
public class SchemaTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        File docFile = new File("C:\\Users\\ahussain\\Desktop\\Xml_Validation\\memory.xml");
        try {
            DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
            parser.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
            parser.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-   noNamespaceSchemaLocation","memory.xsd");
            ErrorChecker errors = new ErrorChecker();
            parser.setErrorHandler(errors);
            parser.parse("memory.xml");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Problem parsing the file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because of this i am also having problem  with `DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding to run configuration add the jar to your classpath,

Project - BuildPath - Configure Build Path - Libraries - Add your jar.

Comment: I will always accept the answer whenever i get the right one,here you go because your answer solved the problem for me